# Why can't I retrieve simple data from an input file and write it to an output file with C++?

Tags: c++

I've been at this homework for days, and I cannot figure out what exactly I am doing wrong.

In short, I am building a simple, basic program in C++ that reads a student name and 5 grades from a file called input.dat, and then writing that data, and organizing it into a separate file called output.dat.

Simple, right?
However, when I check the output file, instead of simple whole numbers, I get insane, exponentially large numbers that repeat themselves.

Please help me out. And go easy on me. I'm 18 and this is my first programming class ever.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in_stream;
    ofstream out_stream;
    in_stream.open("input.dat");
    out_stream.open("output.dat");

    double test1, test2, test3, test4, test5;
    string name1, name2;

    cout.precision(2);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);

    in_stream >> name1 >> name2 >> test1 >> test2 >> test3 >> test4 >> test5;

    out_stream << "Student Name: " << name1 << name2 <<endl
        << "Test Scores: " << test1 << test2 << test3 << test4 << test5 <<endl
        << "Average Test Score: " << ((test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5)/5);

    in_stream.close( );
    out_stream.close( );

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you clean output.data every time after you run the code?

Comment: Adding a test run (i.e. the input and output of the program) might help. Also, during debugging, to avoid any issues with the filesystem you can use `std::cin` and `std::cout` as input/output.

Comment: Your input operations are broken, because you never check the return value. There's no point wasting time on this code until you fix that.

Comment: I edited in the bits you left out. I hope that's right.

Comment: I've tested it with a sample input file, and it works just fine for me, aside from the fact that you're missing spaces between the first and second name, and between all the grades, but that's really easy to fix. For example `cout << name1 << ' ' << name2 << '\n'` works great for getting the space in between the two names. And don't use `endl`. It's a bad habit your teacher has and you should avoid picking it up. (Note that there's a space between the single quotes up there.)

Comment: Omnifarious, thank you so much, I refreshed the page, and everything's fixed, and you have a solution. Wow. I really appreciate your help.

I was wondering if I was running it wrong on my computer or something. I got together with a friend today in class, and I seem to have had everything alright, at least.

Comment: Also, should I use "\n" instead of endl? Yeah, he uses it consistently, and he's the only teacher I've had so far. I appreciate the advice.
I will enter those spaces, and send it to a friend to see if it works.

I appreciate EVERYONE's effort for their time and VERY quick response. I will start using this website now. Thanks.

Comment: You *really* need to check that all those IO's succeeded. It is as simple as `if (in_stream >> name1 >> name2 >> test1 >> test2 >> test3 >> test4 >> test5)...`

Answer (score 0):

So summarizing the comments, the solution should look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in_stream;
    ofstream out_stream;
    in_stream.open("input.dat");
    out_stream.open("output.dat");

    double test1, test2, test3, test4, test5;
    string name1, name2;

    cout.precision(2);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);

    if(in_stream >> name1 >> name2 >> test1 >> test2 >> test3 >> test4 >> test5)
    {
        out_stream << "Student Name: " << name1 << name2 <<endl
            << "Test Scores: " << test1 << " " << test2 << " " << test3 << " " << test4 << " " << test5 << endl
            << "Average Test Score: " << ((test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5)/5);
    }
    else
    {
        out_stream << "Failed to red input file" << endl;
    }

    in_stream.close( );
    out_stream.close( );

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```